# bootstrap custom margin-bottom not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want add margin bottom in bottom of select component that using bootstrap. im add this into my custom css:

```
select.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

and here my select code:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="InputState" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Provinsis <sup>*</sup> </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="">
            <select class="form-control" required id="InputState" name="InputState">
                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="50">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but still no margin with bottom element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found a problem and have solution.
The problem is because i use jquery custom select by select2.

so i modify my custom css like this:

```
.select2-selection {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and it's work

Comment: great! better if you tick the answer and close this question